# Locating AppleCare UK's New Live Online Chat Support?

Tags: applecare

Apparently AppleCare UK has been revamped to include a brand new live online chat support system, where you can chat in a text box with a member of technical support.

How do I locate this ?

Comment: Live support has been around for years in the US. Perhaps it's being rolled out in more countries?

Comment: @bmike Ah... its only just being rolled out in the UK, I shall edit appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple's UK Support page](https://ssl.apple.com/uk/support/contact/) now has a **Get Started** button which will start a *selection* process to narrow down the required support's area.

[image]

After a couple of steps (choosing the product and topic) you'll be prompted to choose between different support options, among which you'll find the **Chat** button will be visible when there are people on staff to answer questions in near real time.

[image: Contact Apple Support UK]

Comment: Fabulous very useful

Comment: I have altered the question to be specific to the UK (as its been a feature of the US support for a number of years now), if that affects your answer at all.